# iCloud mail advanced filter rules

Tags: icloud, email, sort

is there a way to add filter rules for an iCloud for example,  if the Sender is *test@example.net* and Subject contains "test" then move the mail in "test" and flag it as Spam.

I looking for  something like what Gmail and Outlook have. In the iCloud mail settings, in the web I only see some primitive rules that won't do something like this and can have only one condition.

I want the filters to run constantly not only in the Mac Mail.app or in Thunderbird which would only affect mails that I receive while my Mac is online.  They should run all the time so that my mails on my phone also get sorted.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the filters to run constantly … not only in the Mac Mail.app … they should run all the time so that my mails on my phone also get sorted.

This is how the server side rules work.  It’s pretty straightforward to create these rules.  In iCloud Mail, click the gear icon, select *Preferences*, then *Rules*, and add a new rule.

Apple has a great step by step guide on how to [set up Rules on both Mail and iCloud](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/set-up-filtering-rules-mm6b1a3f8a/icloud).

> … I only see some primitive rules that won't do something like this and can have only one condition.

This is a limitation of iCloud Mail; unfortunately there’s no hidden setting to create “advanced” rules. Personally, I found iCloud Mail lacking and instead opted for Outlook.com and hosted Exchange for the advanced features that I need.